# Why material added to ui panel is not visible in android build but works fine in editor window in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui, unity3d-editor, unity3d-shaders

The material added to the UI Panel is working in the editor window but not working in android build. How to fix this?

**Editor Screenshot**
[image]

**Android screenshot**
[image]

**Note:**

1. I have tried adding a shader to "always Included shader" list in the project setting menu. still not fixed.
2. I'm not altering the shader/material in the code.
3. This is worked fine in a previous unity version. (my unity version is 2018.3.11f1)
4. The same material works fine in other game objects (like a cube, etc,.), but not works with any other UI (like buttons, canvas, etc.,)

Answer (score 2):

you should check your shader.
i think you have another shader change the Render Queue.
Add ZTest Off in your shader.It might work